# Is it feasible to build company specific framework that wraps NHibernate?

Tags: entity-framework, zend-framework, nhibernate, entity, feasibility

I heard that companies that use Java technologies, they used to build their own custom Framework that wraps Hibernate. However, is it really feasible for their .Net peers to do the same thing with NHibernate or Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you tell a little more about the business value of your framework. Because there are many frameworks which can work together with NHibernate and add value. Writing one your self you should start with a business case to see if it is a good investment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the repository pattern and a separate project/dll to abstract away the data framework nhibernate / entity framework.  this is a good starting point http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2008/04/04/wrapping-up-nhibernate-in-repositories/

Answer (score 1):

This is almost always a horrible idea - I think Ayende sums it up best in [this article](http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal). In general, you should consider NHibernate itself to be the "wrapper" around your data access - attempting to build an abstraction layer on top of it is probably going to be a losing proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should check out some of the articles on [.NET Junkie's weblog](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/). He wrote several great posts on how to deal with repositories, [queries](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92), [commands](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) and so on. We've been using these in a very large enterprise system where we switch between an in-memory dictionary, an in-memory SQLite database and a production environment using SQL Server or Oracle. Obviously, we use NHibernate for this.